# Passing parameter to a javascript function, which contains a '-'

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a parameter as text which contains multiple '**-**'.

eg. 4f5ff225-70bc-4970-a12d-483beb066c47

But when i pass it.. i get nothing in result. I guess '**-**' is creating problem. Is there any way to pass the above example as it is to the javascript function.

Comment: include your code ... because it works perfectly fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/2z2RR/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, your code looks something like this:

```
 foo(4f5ff225-70bc-4970-a12d-483beb066c47)
```

This is not going to work and there should be some errors in the console.

Pass it as a string (because that's what it is).

```
 var foo = function(s) {
   alert(s);
 }

 foo('4f5ff225-70bc-4970-a12d-483beb066c47')
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it works!! I just had to use "&#39;" to escape the quotes.. and then it runs just fine!! :)